# Using Folium package to show a map of the UK energy consumption but the map does not load but saves

Tags: python, geojson, folium

Initially thought its because of the size of the dataframe but reduced this to only include the 3 relevant columns:

LSOA21NM geometry Mean Electricity Consumption (kWh) per meter

City of London 001A POLYGON ((532151.537 181867.433, 532152.500 18...) 4058.911

City of London 001BPOLYGON ((532634.497 181926.016, 532632.048 18...) 3807.04

This is the code:

```
import folium
import branca.colormap as cm

# Step 1: Import libraries (already done)

# Step 2: Initialize the map
# This centers the map around the mean latitude and longitude of your data
center_lat = simplified_gdf.geometry.centroid.y.mean()
center_lon = simplified_gdf.geometry.centroid.x.mean()
mymap = folium.Map(location=[center_lat, center_lon], zoom_start=10)

# Step 3: Add the choropleth layer
# Using GeoJson to add the choropleth layer
folium.GeoJson(
    simplified_gdf,
    name='choropleth',
    style_function=lambda feature: {
        'fillColor': cm.linear.YlGnBu_09.scale(0, simplified_gdf['Mean Electricity Consumption (kWh) per meter'].max())(feature['properties']['Mean Electricity Consumption (kWh) per meter']),
        'color': 'black',
        'weight': 0.5,
        'dashArray': '5, 5',
        'fillOpacity': 0.7,
    },
    tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['LSOA21NM', 'Mean Electricity Consumption (kWh) per meter'],
        aliases=['LSOA Name', 'Mean Electricity Consumption per Meter (kWh)'],
        localize=True
    )
).add_to(mymap)

# Step 4: Add a colormap legend
colormap = cm.linear.YlGnBu_09.scale(0, simplified_gdf['Mean Electricity Consumption (kWh) per meter'].max()).to_step(index=[0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000])
colormap.caption = 'Mean Electricity Consumption (kWh) per Meter'
colormap.add_to(mymap)

# Step 5: Finalize and display the map
folium.LayerControl().add_to(mymap)

# Save the map to an HTML file (optional)
mymap.save('choropleth_map2.html')

# Display the map in a Jupyter Notebook (if you're using one)
mymap
```

I've tried reducing the dataframe as explained.

I've tried downloading it locally and trying to display it on a browser but no luck

Just checked the file size is 1.1gb is this why?

Comment: What do you mean it does not load? Does it now show up in the Jupyter notebook?